# Weird CSS issue

Tags: html, css

I've been having a weird CSS issue with trying to repeat an image header and for some reason its not working, here is the code, am I doing anything wrong?

```
body {
    background:url(images/bg.png) repeat 0% 0%;
    font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
}
/* this part is not working its only showing the header in its original size I am trying to make it repeat*/

#header {
    width: 100%;
    background: url(header.png) repeat-x;
    height:44px;

}

HTML:
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="header">



    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Can you post your example to jsfiddle?

Answer (score 1):

It's your path. Is your `header.png` in the same path as your CSS document?

If not, use relative pathing, ex:

```
width: 100%;
background: url(../header.png) repeat-x;
height:44px;
```

Add a `../` for each sub folder your in from where the image lies.

Comment: I dont think that is the problem since he is getting the image to display but only once and it is not repeating.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
#header {
    width: 100%;
    background: url(header.png) repeat-x;
    height:44px;
    display:block
}
#wrap {
    width: 100%;
    display:block
}
```

But.. i tested your original code on fiddle ( with another image) and it works good, may be problem is not in `#header`, may be the problem is in another element which has another width.

Comment: But both divs are block level elements to begin with?

Comment: Ya I made a mistake with the #wrap I put it before the header with a small width so it was blocking the repeat. Its working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

You might be trying to size an inline element. Try adding this argument - display:block

Edit: I see that you are using a div, disregard my previous answer.

Answer (score 0):

Works fine here

http://i51.tinypic.com/2ds1ele.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Look at this Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/ksCnL/

This is your code but with a correct image path. If your header.png is in the parent directory use `url('../header.png');`.
If it is in an images folder try `url('../images/header.png');` or `url('/images/header.png');`.

Look for the file location and fix your path.

Comment: He said "/* this part is not working its only showing the header in its original size I am trying to make it repeat*/" which I assume means that it is only showing once but is not getting repeated. If the path was wrong, it would not show even once.

Comment: Ya I dont have an issue with the path, like he said my header is showing its just the repeat is not working. I figured it out was a stupid mistake I put the #wrap before the header with 670 width so it was blocking the repeat. Thanks for trying to help :)